# How can I accurately determine how much someone likes a sound?

Tags: hearing, dopamine

I was thinking about this question the other day. My first instinct was to evaluate the dopamine levels before and after listening to a tune. I proposed this to my friend in the medical field, and she said that it might not be the best way to assess how much someone likes a sound, since dopamine is released when the body feels pleasure. However, she can't think of an alternative. Is there a good way to do this? Preferably something that is feasible to do on human subjects in a non-lab environment (although this might be a lot to ask). Thanks.

Comment: You've rejected "ask them"?

Comment: @swbarnes2 Of course that is a possibility, but I was thinking of something more accurate than good/bad.

Comment: Whether they've actually bought the CD/MP3? Or concert tickets &c?  And on the other side, how much they'd pay for earplugs if trapped in a (pick your genre/artist) concert?

Comment: @jamesqf I was thinking less of a song, more of a tune, but thanks anyway

Comment: @TheBestMagician: What's the difference between a song and a tune, though?  Unless you mean that a song is sung by human voices?  But even then, it's possible to enjoy that simply as music.  I certainly don't understand Gaelic or medieval French, and I struggle with Latin & even Middle English, but I enjoy songs sung in those languages.

Comment: The gold standard would have to be to ask. Any other physiological parameter would just be based on correlation with what people report.